# Vue.js : API doesn't work and show nothing

Tags: vue.js

i have a problem with vue.js and using of API / Axios. Assuming it's easy to solve but I don't find it.

app.js

```js
require('./bootstrap');
    
window.Vue = require('vue');
    
Vue.component('welcome', require('./components/Welcome.vue').default);
    
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

bootstrap.js

```js
window._ = require('lodash');
    
try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
    
    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}
    
window.axios = require('axios');
    
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

My component (components/Welcome.vue):

```html
<template>
    <div>{{ info }}</div>
</template>
       
<script>
    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                info: null
            }
        },
        mounted () {
            axios
                .get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
                .then(response => (this.info = response))
                .catch(error => console.log(error))
        }
    }    
</script>
```

This is the example from Website vue.js!

If I run on local server by npm run watch it shows only a blank site without any error. Console shows only following: info: `null`

Hope enough to help me.

Comment: You're opening the page how exactly?

Comment: As this is part into Laravel Installation: <div id="app" class="wrapper"><welcome></welcome></div> or misunderstood your question? Everthing else works fine with vue but not the API.

Comment: Log the value of `response.data`, using Console.log('response', response.data). What data type is `this.info` supposed to be?